# How can I insert a delay sql statement using PHP?

Tags: php, command, execute

I would like to provide a web site for user, when the user input somethings, I will put it into the DB. But the command won't execute when the user access the .php. I would like to execute after a while.... This is something like this...

```
10:00 am
User makes the request, and saying that the record will write in the DB one hour later. 

11:00 am 
The request execute, and the DB write a new record.
```

How Can I do so? also, I would like to add an ability for user to cancel the request.....Something like this:

```
10:00 am
User makes the request, and saying that the record will write in the DB one hour later. 

10:30 am
User cancels the request.

11:00 am 
Nothing won't execute.
```

Any ideas on that? Thank you.

Comment: Why the delay? Can't you just write the value to the database directly, add a timestamp, and ignore all records that are too new until the waiting period is over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When user input, save that input in database table but set a column(verified) value '0'
- After one hour a [cron job](http://www.sitepoint.com/introducing-cron/) will set column(verified) value as '1'
- If user cancel before verification, delete that record

**Example:**

table **user_input**:

```
user_id | input |    input_time     | verified
   1    |  500  | 2011-01-01 12:20  |    1
   2    |  700  | 2011-01-01 01:20  |    0
```

---

### OR

- create a new table to store input requests
- After one hour a cron job will transer all request to original table.
- If user cancel before one hour, delete that record from requests table.

**Example:**

table **user_input**:

```
user_id | input
   1    |  500 
   2    |  700
```

table **user_requests**:

```
user_id  |  input  |    input_time
   3     |   200   | 2011-01-01 07:20
```

Answer (score 3):

cron is overly complex for this. When you insert into the database, have a column that contains the date and time the post should go live. For example:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (body, effective_date) VALUES ('body text', '" . strtotime('+1 hour') . "'";
```

In the pages that display your content, just add `WHERE effective_date>=NOW()` and it'll exclude pending entries.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workflow to accomplish this:

1. When the user makes a request, log the request to a file
2. Create a cron job to run a separate PHP script which reads the file and inserts the data into a database
3. If the user cancels the request, remove the request from the file.

In the place of "file" you may also log the request to the database in a "pending" table, and perform a similar operation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a different database table where you schedule jobs. Users can add, modify and remove jobs from this table. Then have a cronjob check the table each five or ten minutes, and execute the jobs for the current time.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually like the record to be entered into the DB one hour later you would have to create some kind of **queue** for your entries and setup a script (via **Cron** or other) that checks for records one hour old and inserts them into the database. You haven't specified which database you are working with, but as far as I know there is no DB that gives you the option to do an **insert** command but tell it to **wait one hour before actually doing it**.

If you use a queue then you could have a time stamp on it when the user created it and within one hour from that time stamp the user has the ability to cancel the record.

Your queue should probably reside in your DB as well and could actually be the actual table that the data is meant to end up in. Just use you time stamp to see if one hour has elapsed and mark the record as no longer **cancelable** (if that word exists... hehe). That would mean that the entry is actually written to the DB **before** one hour has passed. But you just have to filter your operations on whether or not an hour has passed since it's creation.